# Pytorch CPU Device index must not be negative

Tags: python, torch

I have a tensor trained with cuda that I want to deploy on a cpu. I have the model running on a [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZlL8BW2t2aMY7LP_lvc8E5WcYVgKmTVW?usp=sharing) GPU runtime, switched to a cpu runtime and tried to port it over.

Apologies for not including a reproducible example, I don't really know what's the best practice if the dataset is on my google drive.

```
model = mymodel()
device = torch.device("cpu")
state_dict = torch.load(loadckpt,map_location=device)
model.load_state_dict(state_dict['model'])
model.eval()
result = model(sample)
```

When I run this, I get the following traceback error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-5336d222ce8f> in <module>()
      8 # right_pad_np = sample["right_pad"]
      9 # disp_est_uint = np.round(disp_est_np * 256).astype(np.uint16)
---> 10 test_sample(sample)

8 frames
/content/CFNet/utils/experiment.py in wrapper(*f_args, **f_kwargs)
     28     def wrapper(*f_args, **f_kwargs):
     29         with torch.no_grad():
---> 30             ret = func(*f_args, **f_kwargs)
     31         return ret
     32 

<ipython-input-25-5336d222ce8f> in test_sample(sample)
      2 def test_sample(sample):
      3     model.eval()
----> 4     disp_ests, pred1_s3_up, pred2_s4 = model(sample['left'], sample['right'])
      5     return disp_ests[-1]
      6 # disp_est_np = tensor2numpy(test_sample(sample))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py in forward(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
    148         with torch.autograd.profiler.record_function("DataParallel.forward"):
    149             if not self.device_ids:
--> 150                 return self.module(*inputs, **kwargs)
    151 
    152             for t in chain(self.module.parameters(), self.module.buffers()):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/content/CFNet/models/cfnet.py in forward(self, left, right)
    546 
    547         mindisparity_s3_1, maxdisparity_s3_1 = self.generate_search_range(self.sample_count_s3 + 1, mindisparity_s3, maxdisparity_s3, scale = 2)
--> 548         disparity_samples_s3 = self.generate_disparity_samples(mindisparity_s3_1, maxdisparity_s3_1, self.sample_count_s3).float()
    549         confidence_v_concat_s3, _ = self.cost_volume_generator(features_left["concat_feature3"],
    550                                                             features_right["concat_feature3"], disparity_samples_s3, 'concat')

/content/CFNet/models/cfnet.py in generate_disparity_samples(self, min_disparity, max_disparity, sample_count)
    464             :disparity_samples:
    465         """
--> 466         disparity_samples = self.uniform_sampler(min_disparity, max_disparity, sample_count)
    467 
    468         disparity_samples = torch.cat((torch.floor(min_disparity), disparity_samples, torch.ceil(max_disparity)),

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/content/CFNet/models/submodule.py in forward(self, min_disparity, max_disparity, number_of_samples)
    295 
    296         multiplier = (max_disparity - min_disparity) / (number_of_samples + 1)   # B,1,H,W
--> 297         range_multiplier = torch.arange(1.0, number_of_samples + 1, 1, device=device).view(number_of_samples, 1, 1)  #(number_of_samples, 1, 1)
    298         sampled_disparities = min_disparity + multiplier * range_multiplier
    299 

RuntimeError: Device index must not be negative
```

My initial thought is obviously what is the device index?

```
device=torch.device('cpu')
print(device.index)

...Output...
None
```

Unsure of what I'm missing. Torch documentation says this should be completely fine. Check out the linked Colab if you want to see the full code.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a little late but I just ran into a similar problem (also getting "Device index must not be negative" in my forward call after moving from gpu to cpu).
At some point in my code I created a tensor with `device = input_data.get_device()`
and the `get_device()` seems to have caused the problem. Doing
`device = input_data.device` solved it for me.